# Flutter: ListTile's trailing children stick together

Tags: android, flutter

I am new to flutter. Trying to achieve the infinite ListTile. The issue is that the children in trailing(with red background) stick together at the center I want them to stick to the top and bottom end which I tried by using `mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween` but the columns height won't expand even after setting `mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max`.

I have tried adding Expand and Flex widgets, also tried using Row Column structure rather that ListView but still the same issue. Only giving height to trailing column worked but wanted it to work dynamically without giving height. Below are links for the code.

1. Image: [ListView trailing issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/87fAx.png)
2. Code with ListTile widget https://www.pastefile.com/IbImGL
3. Code with Row Column https://www.pastefile.com/o9JK6

Comment: You could check the source code of ListTile and see how it works, I recommend you to create your own widget based on Row

Comment: @diegoveloper I have done that, created list using Rows and Columns but the same issue still there, height of column remains the same and I need to give height to increase it but the issue is giving height is not the solution it might break on different resolution.

Comment: Could you paste your code without using ListTile?

Comment: @diegoveloper, I have updated the question with the codes, please look into it, Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, the easy solution could using a fixed height , you can calculate the value based on the size of your screen using :

```
 MediaQuery.of(context).size.height
```

Another solution is using `IntrinsicHeight` Widget, but be carefully because the description of the Widget says that is very expensive

```
        IntrinsicHeight(
                      child: Row(
                        children: [
                          buildLeftSection(),
                          buildMiddleSection(),
                          buildRightSection()
                        ],
                      ),
                    )



    Widget buildRightSection() {
      return Column(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
        children: <Widget>[new Text("Title"), new Text("Title")],
      );
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, I will try Media Querry and I will let you know if it worked.

Comment: sure, both options works :) let me know if my answer help you

Comment: Yes, both the codes did worked since IntrinsicHeight was a expensive resource I have used the Media Query. Hope that works for all devices. Thanks for the help.